# Работа/остановка скрипта при определенном разрешении

Tags: javascript

День добрый. Есть js скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($(window).width() > 700) {
    $('#to-catalog').click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #ajax-right-col';
        $('#ajax-right-col').hide('fast',loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#ajax-right-col').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#ajax-right-col').show('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Мне необходимо настроить работу этого кода так, чтобы он срабатывал на разрешении только меньше 700 пикселей. В противном случае - на разрешениях выше - скрипт срабатывать не должен. Подскажите, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#to-catalog').click(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 700) {
      var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #ajax-right-col';
      $('#ajax-right-col').hide('fast',loadContent);
      function loadContent() {
        $('#ajax-right-col').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
      }
      function showNewContent() {
        $('#ajax-right-col').show('normal');
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```